# check a particular pattern of file present using ANT

Tags: ant

I want to search a file of particular pattern.
For e.g. : suppose I have 2 files:

1. filename$1.class
2. filename$2.class

now I want to search for `filename$*.class` , if exists then I will do something.
please advise to search this pattern in ANT.

I have done some homework. Using available tag, I can find single file, but not able to find files with a particular pattern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check multiple file exists or not using ANT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698694/check-multiple-file-exists-or-not-using-ant)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FileSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)

`<fileset dir="your/dir" includes="filename$*.class"/>`

Comment: Hi Jean, 
First I want to check whether the file for this pattern exists.
And, if files exists, then update to some variable which stores all the found files.
So to achieve that, I have few doubts:
1) As my file path is absolute path, can't I directly put the full file path in includes and make dir="/". Otherwise I have to split my path.?
2) where all these included file stores?? like If I want to use the matched file, can I do that??

Comment: any advise will be helpful.

Comment: I am still stuck ... can anybody answer, how to check multiple file exists using wildcard '*'.