# Check multiple file exists or not using ANT

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am using ANT to check count for set of files in two jars.
I am not able to check whether the files of same pattern exists or not.

for e.g. I have 2 files like /host/user/dir1/ABC1.txt and /host/user/dir1/ABC2.txt.

now i want to check whether the file of pattern "/host/user/dir1/ABC*" present or not ??

I can check individual file /host/user/dir1/ABC1.txt, using available tag, but not able to check the files for specific pattern.

thanks in advance.

For individual file, following works fine:

```
<if>
    <available file="${client.classes.src.dir}/${class_to_be_search}.class"/>
    <then>
         <echo> File ${client.classes.src.dir}/${class_to_be_search}.class FOUND in src dir 

         </echo>
         <echo> Update property client.jar.packages.listOfInnerClass</echo>
    </then>
    <else>
         <echo> File ${client.classes.src.dir}/${class_to_be_search}.class NOT FOUND      in src dir.  
         </echo>
    </else>
</if>
```

But i want to search for multiple files:
something like :  ${dir.structure}/${class_to_be_search}$*.class

Comment: Can you add code that you actually use (this one with individual file check)?

Comment: For individual file, following works fine:

<if>
<available file="${client.classes.src.dir}/${class_to_be_search}.class"/>
<fileset >
     <then>
     <echo> File ${dir.structure}/${class_to_be_search}.class FOUND in src dir. 
    </echo>
    <echo> Update property client.jar.packages.listOfInnerClass </echo>
                </then>
                <else>
                        <echo> File ${client.classes.src.dir}/${class_to_be_search}.class NOT FOUND  in src dir. </echo>
                </else>
                </if>

I want to search ${dir.structure}/${class_to_be_search}$*.class

Comment: Edit your question and paste it there. Don't forget to format this into readable form.

Comment: @Patryk Roszczyniała : questiion edited with example.

Answer (score 3):

The [if task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) is not part of core ANT.

The following example shows how it can be done using the ANT [condition task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html). You can use whatever pattern you want in the fileset. The target execution is subsequently conditional on how the "file.found" property has been set:

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

    <fileset id="classfiles" dir="build" includes="**/*.class"/>

    <condition property="file.found">
        <resourcecount refid="classfiles" when="greater" count="0"/>
    </condition>

    <target name="run" depends="found,notfound"/>

    <target name="found" if="file.found">
        <echo message="file found"/>
    </target>

    <target name="notfound" unless="file.found">
        <echo message="file not found"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: You have made target="run" as default. This means it will run first by default. Right? This "run" target is depend on found/notfound targets which in-turn uses "file.found" condition.
i want to know when this condition task gets executed and set file.found=true/false ??

Comment: @MayurSharma That is the purpose of the "condition" task. It's executed when the build is initialised and sets the property. This property in turn controls whether the "found" and "notfound" targets do anything.