# Ant resource exists check

Tags: java, ant, resources, conditional-statements

I have problem testing file existence with ant. I want to check if files exist in target `test`, and if not, I want download files in target `download`. But the `download` target will be executed always (if files exist or not). Can anybody show what is wrong?

```
<!-- Test lib files if exist -->
<target name="test">
    <condition property="is.resource.exists" value="true" else="false">
        <and>
            <resourceexists>
                <file file="${lib}/jdom-2.0.5.jar" />
            </resourceexists>
            <resourceexists>
                <file file="${lib}/miglayout-4.0-swing.jar" />
            </resourceexists>
        </and>
    </condition>
</target>

<!-- Download lib files if not exist -->
<target name="download" if="is.resource.exists" depends="test">
    <exec dir="${lib}" executable="${lib}/get-libs.sh" />
</target>
```

Comment: Does this fix ya http://stackoverflow.com/a/520567/1083581

Comment: This one tells about multiple files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698694/check-multiple-file-exists-or-not-using-ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<target>` with an `if` attribute will execute if the property in the `if` attribute **exists**. Similarly,  a `<target>` with an `unless` attribute will execute if the property in the `unless` attribute **doesn't exist**. It doesn't matter what the value of the property is: true, false, kumquat, or whatever.

Replace the `if="is.resource.exists"` with `unless="is.resource.exists"` and you should be good.

Comment: Note that `else="false"` should be also removed from condition as it forces `is.resource.exists` property to be defined even if resource is not really present. `if` and `unless` check only existence of property, not it's value.